# Next.js App Router, specify revalidation on server side functions that don't use 'fetch'

Tags: next.js, vercel

I am using the new App Router in my Next.js project.
My pages are filled with content from a Markdown file fetched from a bucket. On my Vercel hosting, these pages are cached forever, so changes to the Markdown file aren't shown.

[The documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#incremental-static-regeneration-getstaticprops-with-revalidate) shows how to specify cache expiration time, within the `fetch` parameters. But my functions does not use `fetch`, it uses the Firebase SDK.

I've also tried adding an extra step of creating an internal api route that returns the file's contents, and then the page route could `fetch` that api route, specifying the proper revalidation parameters. But Next.js does not seem to allow fetching internal api routes from within server side.

---

Below is the code for one of my routes, where `downloadFromStorage` returns the contents from the file in the bucket.

```
import {TextPage} from "@/components";
import {downloadFromStorage} from "@/app/api/file-handling";

export default async function PageTerms(props) {
    const text=await downloadFromStorage('pages/terms.md')
    return (<TextPage text={text.toString()}/>)
}
```

(the `downloadFromStorage` function)

```
import {storage} from "./firebase"
export async function downloadFromStorage(filename, bucketName = BUCKET) {
    const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
    const file = bucket.file(filename);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        file.download((err, contents) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            resolve(contents);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a route segment configuration with the `revalidate` option. This will then revalidate the entire segment based on the exported integer.

```
// revalidate every 60 seconds
export const revalidate = 60;
```

You can learn more about segment configurations and the revalidate option in the [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#revalidate).

Comment: How to revalidate on demand with `revalidatePath`?

Comment: @jstorm31 Take a look at the official documentation [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidatePath).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've gone through the documentation, but it's not stated very clear. The give 80 % focus to Fetch API and time based invalidation in the docs. Turns out I used `revalidatePath` in a client component. Moving it to server action worked for me.

Comment: @jstorm31 Pardon me but I doubt that, the documentation I have linked in my previous comment inside this thread **very clearly** describes the usage in server components and route handlers.